# On the interpretation of "walked to the station at 9 o'clock"

Tags: verbs, expressions, meaning

I want to confirm what a book says. It says:

1. I went to the station at 9 o'clock.
2. I walked to the station at 9 o'clock.

Sentence (1) has the following two meaning:

a. I left for the station at 9 o'clock.

b. I got to the station at 9 o'clock.

Sentence (2), on the other hand, has only one meaning: I left for the station at 9 o'clock.

Do you agree with this description? If so, how do you express this situation in one sentence: I walked to the station, and I got to the station at 9 o'clock. "I got to the station walking at 9 o'clock"?

Comment: I would use the single sentence "I walked to the station, and I got to the station at 9 o'clock."

Comment: I think this is not constructive. There are lots of possibilities. "I walked to the station and got there at 9 o'clock"; "I walked to the station and arrived there at 9 o'clock"; "I arrived at the station by foot at 9 o'clock"; "I got to the station by foot at 9 o'clock"; "I went to the station by foot and was there at 9 o'clock"; I am running out of space already.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence #1 seems ambiguous because you can't tell if the writer left for or arrived at the station at 9 o'clock.

Sentence #2, to me, seems to imply the writer began walking to the station at 9 o'clock.

Sentence #1 could be restated as:

***"I left for the station at 9 o'clock."***

or

***"I arrived at the station at 9 o'clock."***

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, this question seemed to be closed, but your answer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sentence 2 is far from unambiguous though. If I left for the station at 8:45, and arrived at the station at 9:15, then I might say "I walked to the station at nine o'clock," meaning I had been walking at 9:00, and, by extension, during the minutes immediately before and after. P.S. (to the OP): Don't lament that your question was closed – study the reason it was closed. As @RegDwighт said, you've given sentences that have a wide array of possible interpretations depending on context, and _that_ is the true answer to your question. If you mean to say you arrived at 9, then say you arrived at 9.